# How to generate associations between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activemodel

I am wondering how to do the association in Rails correct. First I create a City model and an Organisation. Now I want to have an Organisation have a City... this is done by adding the `has_many` and `has_one` associations. After that I run `rake db:migrate`. But somehow it does not create a field `city` or `city_id` in my database model. Do I have to do this myself? Shouldn't rails now create a foreign key constraint in the database?

To see if it has worked I am using `rails c` and type in `Organisation`
the answer is the following:

```
=> Organisation(id: integer, name: string, description: string, url: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Please excuse my stupid question... I am a beginner in Rails and everything is still very unfamiliar.

Thanks!

---

City:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organisations
end
```

Organisation:

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :city
end
```

Create City:

```
class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :country

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Create Organisation:

```
class CreateOrganisations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :organisations do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.string :url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with this.

1. You need to specify a `belongs_to` on the other side of a `has_many` or `has_one` association. The model that defines a `belongs_to` association is where the foreign key belongs.

   So if an Organization `has_one :city`, then a City needs to `belongs_to :organization`. Alternatively, if a City `has_one :organization`, then the Organization needs to `belongs_to :city`.

   Looking at your setup, it looks like you want the `belongs_to` definition inside the `City` model.
2. The migrations aren't built off the model definitions. Instead, they are built from the `db/migrations` folder. A migration is created when you run the `rails g model` command (or `rails g migration`). In order to get a foreign key, you need to tell the generator to create it.

   ```
   rails generate model organization name:string description:string url:string city_id:integer
   ```

   Or

   ```
   rails generate model city name:string description:string url:string organization_id:integer
   ```

Comment: Just for understanding. I can't just edit the db/migrate/...create_cities.rb and then run rake db:migrate? I need to create a new migration? (For the case, I forgot to model the assosiation at generation time?) Do I have to change both ends? Organisation and City?

Comment: @Mark No you can't if the migration has already been applied. Create a new migration and use the `change_table` method to add the association column to your `organisations` table.

Comment: You only need to edit one of the tables. That is, the table whose corresponding model defines the `belongs_to` association.

Comment: Also, make sure to put foreign key constraints in your DB. The easiest way to do that is with the [Foreigner](http://www.rubygems.org/gems/foreigner) gem.